# Correct vCard format for iOS devices?

Tags: objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

In iOS 5 and above, Apple introduced the `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation` method, which is pretty useful in feeding a vCard to the Address Book and getting back the ABRecordRefs for the persons created.

However, the Apple vCard seems to be (at least a bit) different from a standard vCard, as I have found out while trying to add standard vCards to the Address Book. Is there a page somewhere detailing what the Apple-format for a vCard should be?

Thanks!

Comment: Which .vcf files had problems for you, i.e. any specific fields, etc? The only thing I found at the moment is that vCard file size should be less than 256Kb.

Comment: @NickolayO. mostly the `PHOTO` field. seems like it expects a combination of formatting between vcard 2.1 and vcard 3.0.

Comment: Could you attach sample vcard file? (PS. doc says: Address Book supports vCard version 3.0.)

Comment: As @ahmet said - if you could attach the .vcf file you've tried that would help :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation` docs state that [vCard version 3 is the supported protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation). Unfortunately if you're having troubles with a standard vCard I'm not sure how to help - I did a fair bit of searching (that bounty is good motivation :P) and wasn't able to find any further information.

I don't have my iPhone on me to test, but [this guy](http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2011/04/vcard-qr-code-iphone-android-blackberry.html) claims to have successfully imported the following, v2.1 vCard on an iPhone 4 using a QR scanner app (which *might* be using the API in question). [The 3.0 spec is a superset of the 2.1 spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#Properties) - can you try this vCard and let me know if it works?

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:;Company Name
FN:Company Name
ORG:Company Name
TEL;WORK;VOICE;PREF:+16045551212
TEL;WORK;FAX:+16045551213
ADR;WORK;POSTAL;PARCEL;DOM;PREF:;;123 main street;vancouver;bc;v0v0v0;canada
EMAIL;INTERNET;PREF:user@example.com
URL;WORK;PREF:http://www.example.com/
NOTE:http://www.example.com/
CATEGORIES:BUSINESS,WORK
UID:A64440FC-6545-11E0-B7A1-3214E0D72085
REV:20110412165200
END:VCARD
```

You can read the official 3.0 spec [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2425) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426).

As a last ditch solution, there are [plenty of vCard parsers out there](https://github.com/search?q=.vcf&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Repositories&l=Objective-C) - it's a dead simple protocol. You could just take any of these (or write one yourself) and manually add the contact to the Address Book using [ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation).

Comment: @aaronsnoswell, are you aware of similar Apple documentation pertaining to vCard 4.0?

Comment: CATEGORIES:BUSINESS,WORK
 
cannot serialization you have any solution

Answer (score 1):

I've created a backwards compatible [VCard class](https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard), that generates .vcf files. But for iOS devices < iOS 8, the class exports to .ics files (VCards are then wrapped in a VCalendar file) because thats the only way to get things working on older iOS versions!

Used by thousands of people! Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard)

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 9 / iPadOS 9 / watchOS 2.0 / macOS 10.11 you should use the `Contacts` framework instead with the formatter class `CNContactVCardSerialization` documented at

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactsuserdefaults

Unfortunately, i no longer see a mention of the vCard version(s) that are supported.